# Can't use/login VPS (Error: Unable to exchange ecryption keys)

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-16.04, vps

today I found out I couldn't login to my VPS (Ubuntu 16).
Yesterday i make this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-restrict-a-user-to-a-specific-directory

So my phpmyadmin thor arror when login arror too: # 2002

I cant login to SFTP and via Putty.

How can I fix this without re-installing VPS and lose data?

EDIT: VPS provider me get access to local console VPS so i am on VPS but how this fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing anything risks making the problem worse. Your first step should be logging in via console, backing up and pushing the backup to another system you have full control over.

Its difficult to prpvide a good answer without knowing exactly what you have done, but it seems highly likely you have messed up the sshd config.  I would check if sshd is running, and look at the log files for hints, and either restart sshd if its not running or fix errors induced in the config and restart ssh.

Assuming you can't do that much the less controlled option would be to reinstall ssh.  Start by

```
  mv /etc/ssh /etc/ssh-broken
```

To back up the old ssh config. Then force ubuntu to reinstall it -
      sudo apt-get --purge remove openssh-server
      sudo apt-get install openssh-server

You might need to restart ssh with a command like /etc/init.d/sshd restart

Comment: I've already found out where I made a mistake. I run this command `chmod -R o-r /` but i try fix by `chmod -R o+r /` and now have access to phpmyadmin so i make backup databses. But VPS still throw erro when i try login via SFTP or putty, i was check SSH configs and its correct

Comment: Yoy need to reinstall your system. It will be orfers if magnitude less work then unpickling your permissions mess securely.

Comment: i try reinstall ssh and new created users can normal use putty and sftp only old users created before cant login show Error: Authetication by password failed. So i reacreated all user and now work good only root user cant use.

Comment: Your /etc/sshd_config probably has a line like PermitRootLogin no - i'd recommend you leave this as is unless you *really* require it for a specific reason  - best practice dictates people log in as regular users and use su or sudo to become root. Its an important security step, and reduces risk. If root login is required, you should add an AllowUsers directive to lock this down to specifics IPs and also enforce key-based authentication (ie disallow password autjentication).